# How to apply CIFilter to video in Swift without waiting to process

Tags: ios, swift, video-processing, core-image, cifilter

I am currently developing a feature in one of my apps where users can add photos and videos to a post. They have the ability to record video or taking a picture, but afterwards I want to give them full control over the output by applying filters or changing brightness, contrast, exposure, ...

This is relatively easy for photo. To streamline the workflow, I use a third party library called [BBMetalImage](https://github.com/Silence-GitHub/BBMetalImage). This works great, I can apply filters to photo as well as video, but it takes a long time to process the video, which I don't want for my users. A 15 second clip can quickly take upwards of 20 - 30 seconds to process when applying a filter.

I currently do it like this:

```
var lookupFilterName: String! = "lookup_1"
let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(NSUUID().uuidString).mp4")
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
videoWriter = BBMetalVideoWriter(url: outputURL, frameSize: BBMetalIntSize(width: 480, height: 600))
videoSource = BBMetalVideoSource(url: currentVideoURL!)
videoSource.audioConsumer = videoWriter
if(filter != 0) {
    lookupFilterName = "lookup_\(filter)"
}
let lookupFilter = BBMetalLookupFilter(lookupTable: UIImage(named: lookupFilterName)!.bb_metalTexture!)
videoSource.add(consumer: lookupFilter).add(consumer: videoWriter)
videoSource.audioConsumer = videoWriter
videoWriter.start()
videoSource.start { [weak self] (_) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.videoWriter.finish {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if(self.currentVideoURL != nil) {
                self.queuePlayer?.pause()
                self.queuePlayer?.removeAllItems()
                if let playerLayer = self.playerLayer {
                    playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
                self.currentFinalVideoURL = outputURL
                let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: outputURL)
                self.queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem])
                self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.queuePlayer)
                self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.queuePlayer!, templateItem: playerItem)
                self.videoPreview.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
                self.playerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.25)
                self.playerLayer?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                self.queuePlayer?.play()
                self.videoWriter = nil
                self.videoSource = nil
            } else {
                self.videoWriter = nil
                self.videoSource = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't get me wrong. It does the job: it returns the video with the filter applied. Basically what's happening is, it takes the source URL of the original video, applies a filter to it, writes it to another temporary path and then displays this video to the user.

In my opinion, this has to be possible much quicker. I started looking at other applications, especially Instagram, where, when you apply a filter, it changes immediately (doesn't even take a second) and continues playing the video without restarting from the first frame. This is what I actually want.

I looked into this a bit already and figured out I should use CIFilter, because Core Image provides a very fast and reliable way to manipulate photo (and video?).

So my questions are:

1. Will I be able to apply custom-made lookup filters or LUTs when using CIFilter, or am I restricted to the built-in filters provided in the Core Image framework (such as GaussianBlur etc.)?
2. How should I go about changing the video "in real time", without delay for the end user? I read somewhere that this is done using a buffer, after which each frame of the video is manipulated with the desired effect and played back in real time. Any reference or example on how to achieve this? I have no idea where to start on this specific matter. I would also like to be able to export this video when the user stopped editing (filters, brightness, contrast, ...).

Cheers! All information is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**AVFoundation** framework makes easy processing video frame by frame. It everytime generates pixel buffer frame from video at current time and let you add any effect on frame as you like ( filter, brightness, contrast whatever you want). Processing frame at realtime can be done on GPU. **OpenGL**, **Metal** these can be used for that. It will also help you to use your own custom-made filter. You can follow this [link](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/metal-video-processing-ios-tvos/) to start.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be done on the GPU. Accelerate.vImage is fast enough to process video frames in real-time, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/real-time_video_effects_with_vimage

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: Thanks Al Mamun Akash. I'm looking into it! @SimonGladman would it be better to use vImage or is Metal, specifically the BBMetalImage library I'm using right now, also a possibility? Would doing it on the GPU affect my application?

Comment: You can do real-time video processing using either Metal or Accelerate.vImage. Which is "better" very much depends on the context and your requirements. You should probably explore both techniques to decide which is best for you.